# Connect 2 LANs with 1 router

Tags: router, lan, subnet

I have a small business with 3 Windows 10 PCs, 2 NVRs, and several cameras.  My NVRs cannot monitor more than 16 cameras so I separated the initial single LAN into two LANs by using different IP addresses. LAN1 (192.168.1.0) for the 3 PCs, NVR1, the C7 Archer router, and several cameras. LAN2 for NVR2 and it's cameras (192.168.2.0).

LAN1 has internet access. LAN 2 does not.

Windows 10 allowed me to program the LAN2 NVR2 to 192.168.2.2, mask 255.255.255.0, and no gateway.  The LAN2 cameras also have no gateway configured.  So NVR2 and it's cameras are communicating.

How can I establish a connection to the router (192.168.1.1) from NVR2 (192.168.2.2)?  NVR2 does not have wireless capabilities, and I've never tried using a VLAN.  Should I just install a wireless adapter?  Can I configure a static route for NVR2 to see the router/internet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the devices dont have a default gateway, the easiest way to solve this and other issues is to add one   If that is not an option you can put static routes on each device to the router fir the others subnet.

There are some other options but they are not a great idea and may not be supported by your router. (arp hacks or port mapping)

Comment: The only router uses an address in the other subnet.  I don't think that gateway works (I tried it).  I could put the NVR2 address as the gateway for the cameras I suppose, but that won't help me get NVR2 to the internet.  I'm not on-site until Thursday, and will try to set a static route to NVR2 in the router then.